# Flex mx:window transparency control

Tags: air, flex4, window, flex4.6

I am working in flex 4.6 air application in which i open a mx:window (new window).
How can i control the transparency of this this window by using slider value.I mean if i change the value of slider from 0-100 the transparency of this window should be changed.

If any one have any idea please tell me

Thanks

Comment: Hey. What property did you bind to the slider.value? Is this where you're having the issue?

Comment: protected function slider_changeHandler(event:SliderEvent):void
   {    toastWindow.setStyle("backgroundAlpha", slider.value);    
   }
on change of slider value.

Comment: I dont think backgroundAlpha is an accessible style for Flex 4 components. Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6258757/flex-4-transparent-background-problem